# remove x axis and the associated space on gig-lot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use `grid.arrange()` to combine two graphs (where the first is just a simple y axis).

But there is a lot of space associated with the first simple y axis. Is there a way to remove this?

Please see attached code below. There is also the data in put format.
Please see attached code below. There is also the data in put format.
Please see attached code below. There is also the data in put format.
Please see attached code below. There is also the data in put format.

```
left_axis <- ggplot(fig2_data, aes(y = tox_outcome)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev) +
  theme_manuscript(base_size = 12)
 
right_panel <- ggplot(fig2_data) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = n, y = cohort, fill = tox_outcome_bool), stat = 'identity', position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ tox_outcome, ncol = 1, strip.position = 'top') +
  theme_manuscript(base_size = 12) +
  scale_fill_jco() +
  geom_text(aes(x = n, y = cohort, label = label_white), position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE, vjust = 0.5), size = 4, color = 'gray90') +
  geom_text(aes(x = n, y = cohort, label = label_black), position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE, vjust = 0.5), size = 4) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_discrete(name = '', labels = c("Q3W", "Q6W")) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()
  )

grid.arrange(left_axis, right_panel, nrow = 1)
```

Here is the data:

```
> dput(fig2_data)
structure(list(tox_outcome = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("severe_tox_g2plus", "severe_tox_g3plus", 
"hosp_in_18w_bool", "tx_stopped_for_tox", "GI_tox_bool", "Hepatobiliary_tox_bool", 
"Endocrine_tox_bool", "Skin_tox_bool", "General_tox_bool", "Renal_tox_bool"
), class = "factor"), cohort = c("q6w_post", "q6w_post", "q3w_post", 
"q3w_post", "q6w_post", "q6w_post", "q3w_post", "q3w_post", "q6w_post", 
"q6w_post", "q3w_post", "q3w_post", "q6w_post", "q6w_post", "q3w_post", 
"q3w_post", "q6w_post", "q6w_post", "q3w_post", "q3w_post", "q6w_post", 
"q6w_post", "q3w_post", "q3w_post", "q6w_post", "q6w_post", "q3w_post", 
"q3w_post", "q6w_post", "q6w_post", "q3w_post", "q3w_post", "q6w_post", 
"q6w_post", "q3w_post", "q3w_post", "q6w_post", "q6w_post", "q3w_post", 
"q3w_post"), tox_outcome_bool = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Yes", "No"), class = "factor"), n = c(82L, 
38L, 20L, 38L, 45L, 24L, 96L, 96L, 52L, 42L, 22L, 94L, 13L, 52L, 
59L, 43L, 15L, 1L, 66L, 78L, 50L, 55L, 27L, 73L, 95L, 98L, 65L, 
93L, 67L, 13L, 40L, 98L, 69L, 61L, 36L, 77L, 54L, 48L, 91L, 0L
), label_white = c(82L, NA, 20L, NA, 45L, NA, 96L, NA, 52L, NA, 
22L, NA, 13L, NA, 59L, NA, 15L, NA, 66L, NA, 50L, NA, 27L, NA, 
95L, NA, 65L, NA, 67L, NA, 40L, NA, 69L, NA, 36L, NA, 54L, NA, 
91L, NA), label_black = c(NA, 38L, NA, 38L, NA, 24L, NA, 96L, 
NA, 42L, NA, 94L, NA, 52L, NA, 43L, NA, 1L, NA, 78L, NA, 55L, 
NA, 73L, NA, 98L, NA, 93L, NA, 13L, NA, 98L, NA, 61L, NA, 77L, 
NA, 48L, NA, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: large gap between two ggplots]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `margin` of your scale plot. You mean something like this:

```
library(ggsci)
library(gridExtra)
    left_axis <- ggplot(fig2_data, aes(y = tox_outcome)) +
    scale_y_discrete(limits = rev) +
    theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,-6,0,3), "cm"),
          element_blank())
    # theme_manuscript(base_size = 12)
  
  right_panel <- ggplot(fig2_data) +
    geom_bar(aes(x = n, y = cohort, fill = tox_outcome_bool), stat = 'identity', position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)) +
    facet_wrap( ~ tox_outcome, ncol = 1, strip.position = 'top') +
   # theme_manuscript(base_size = 12) +
    scale_fill_jco() +
    geom_text(aes(x = n, y = cohort, label = label_white), position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE, vjust = 0.5), size = 4, color = 'gray90') +
    geom_text(aes(x = n, y = cohort, label = label_black), position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE, vjust = 0.5), size = 4) +
    theme(strip.text.x = element_blank()) +
    scale_y_discrete(name = '', labels = c("Q3W", "Q6W")) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          axis.line.x = element_blank(),
          axis.line.y = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "none",
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()
    )
  
  grid.arrange(left_axis, right_panel, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`grid.arrange()` by default gives each cell an equal amount of space. If you want a close fit around a specific `grob,` you should query its size and explicitly pass it.

Sample code:

```
grid.arrange(left_axis, right_panel, nrow = 1, widths=c(1,4))
```

Plot:

[image]

or even better  `grid.arrange(left_axis, right_panel, nrow = 1, widths=c(1,4.2))`

[image]